# how to make for loop in async.parallel in node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have a code snippet like the following.

```
async.parallel({

    foo: function(call) {

      request.get('...?node=foo', function (error, response, body) {

        var last=JSON.parse(body);
        call(null,last.data.result);
      });

    },
    bar: function(call) {
      request.get('...node=bar', function (error, response, body) {

        var last=JSON.parse(body);
        call(null,last.data.result);
      });
    }
  }, function(err, results) {
    callback(results)
  });
```

but I want to that in loop...that is to say,like the following.

```
var node = ['foo', 'bar'];
async.parallel({

  for (var i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
    node[i]: function(call) {

      request.get('...?node=' + node[i] + '', function(error, response, body) {

        var last = JSON.parse(body);
        call(null, last.data.result);
      });

    }
  }

}, function(err, results) {
  callback(results)
});
```

it does not work...how to make it?
can you help me?

Comment: [`async.map()`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map)

Answer (score 1):

You have one of two options. One is to read the documentation for [`async.map()`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map), which would be the more canonical approach using `async`.

That would look something like this:

```
async.map(['foo', 'bar'], function (node, callback) {
  request.get('...?node=' + encodeURIComponent(node), function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) return callback(error)
    var last = JSON.parse(body)
    callback(null, last.data.results)
  })
}, function (error, results) {
  // handle error
  callback(results)
})
```

Your second option would be to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) with a synchronous [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), removing the dependency for `async` entirely, though you'll probably want a polyfill like [`bluebird`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) until Promises are used in more substantial percentage of browsers.

Here's how you'd implement the latter solution using native Promises:

```
Promise.all(['foo', 'bar'].map(function (node) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request.get('...?node=' + encodeURIComponent(node), function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) return reject(error)
      var last = JSON.parse(body)
      resolve(last.data.result)
    })
  })
})).then(function (results) {
  callback(results)
}).catch(function (error) {
  // handle error
})
```